# graph of user activity in android

Tags: android, graph, progress

I am creating an android application and its name is "exercise challenge ". I am facing a problem while creating a graph.

I am having an activity "air squat " and when user presses start button then I want to do following actions:

1. Save it with time and date (user used this exercise).
2. Draw a graph
   may be a circle graph or line graph and that graph should represent
   user activity i.e which exercise is done by user on which date .

Kindly help me solve this problem, and this graph should be drawn in a new class "progress".

Comment: Please add code that you've tried.

Comment: i want logic or something that i can search on google to get started on this thing

Comment: You can check  [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)